# Mockito test environment variable arguments

Tags: java, junit, mockito

i have this method:

```
public class Main {
    private static String processID;
    private static String inputPath;
    private static String outputPath;

    public static void main(String[] args){
            setProcessID(args[0]);
            setInputPath(args[1]);
            setOutputPath(args[2]);
            try {
                if(getProcessID().equals("Gecs0GdprCF")) {
                    log.info("*** STARTING ANONYMISATION***");
                    gdprService.executeShadowingCF(getOutputPath());
                    log.info("*** ANONYMISATION SUCCESSFULLY ***");
                }
                else if(getProcessID().equals("Gecs0GdprNDG")){
                    gdprService.executeShadowingNDG(getOutputPath());
                }
                else log.info("*** PROCESS NOT SUPPORTED ***");
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ex.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(os));
                log.error(new String(os.toByteArray()));
                log.info("*** BATCH FAILED ***");
            }
        }
}
```

I have to make a junit test on it using Mockito.
I have made this method:

```
@Test
    public void testMain() {
        Main main = new Main();
        String[] args = new String[10];

        args[1]="Gecs0GdprCF";
        Main.setInputPath("");
        Main.setOutputPath("");
        Main.setProcessID("Gecs0GdprCF");
        Main.getInputPath();
        Main.getOutputPath();
        Main.getProcessID();
        Main.main(args);
    }
```

But coverage is not incremented by it.
It says that i never enter in the first if clause. How i can modifiy my test to enter in the first if clause?

Comment: You are setting the process id in `args` array for index 1 and retriving it from index 0 ?

Comment: `args[1]="Gecs0GdprCF"` ->`args[0]="Gecs0GdprCF"`

Comment: yes!!!! this is the problem!! thank you so much :)

Comment: In your main `ProcessID` is taken from `args[0]`, in test you assign that value to `args[1]`. And calling `setInputPath()` and so on in test is pointless as you overwrite those values in the main anyway based on `args`.